# Fire jQuery live event with native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, google-chrome-extension

I have an event on a page that I need to fire from a Chrome Extension. I do not have access to modify the page's JavaScript.

```
$(selector).live("click", fn);
```

I need to trigger this with native JS in my Chrome extension, like this:

```
selectorElement.click(); //doesn't work
```

Of course that above won't work because the `live` function is being used. How can I trigger it though?

Thanks!

Comment: I am sure I have implemented the same thing as you have described above. There is no reason why shouldn't it work. The page and chrome extensions share complete DOM with each other, including the events.

Comment: Just to be 100% clear, you're running your extension code in a content script or via `executeScript`, correct?

Comment: @apsillers it is indeed a content script

Comment: @juzerali i get a "Object has not method 'click'" error in chrome

Comment: Ohh I just remember I had got same message. What I had done was that I didn't wrap the object in jQuery. I simply fired click event using plain javascript like this `document.getElementById('id').click()`. See if that works for you.

Comment: @juzerali that is what i was doing and it wasnt working. fortunately apsillers pointed me in the right direction. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have jQuery, you can fire DOM events using [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent):

```
var selector = "#...";
var elmList = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
elm[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
```

This code fires on the first element matching the selector, but it could be modified to loop over `elmList` if you needed to fire on several elements at once.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)?

```
$(selector).trigger('click');
```

Of course, `trigger()` should be used on a jQuery object (hence the `$(selector)`)
.

Comment: unfortunately i can only use native javascript to do this. i do not have access to `trigger`. thanks!